# Embed a Power BI report in a wix site

Tags: powerbi, velo

I have followed all of the documentation to successfully run the Power BI Embedded code on my local machine. All of the Azure AD permissions are working correctly and I would now like to put this report onto a Wix website. Could anybody please point me in the right direction? I would like the simplest implementation possible but I can't use the 'Publish to web' or 'Embed' functions within Power BI as it's for users outside of my organisation. I'm also tied to Wix for the foreseeable future so have to use their infrastructure I believe.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I have managed to get the report working exactly as I would like on my localhost, I need to now have this on a Wix website. I'm not sure how to link the two together or what I have to change in order to accomplish this. Sorry for not being clear!
[image: My Report]

Answer (score 3):

The process is documented here [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers), and also with a sample app [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/App%20Owns%20Data).  But you'll have to figure out how to authenticate to Power BI, and generate the Embed Token in your environment.

The REST APIs are all documented.  Eg for [Embed Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embedtoken), and for [Azure Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/), but you need to call these from your back-end.  Not from javascript on the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your support David, please see my updated question. I have a screenshot to show my report working as I would like. I just need to get that embedded onto Wix (I say "just" but I've been researching for hours now and don't know what to do next!)